# SonarQube Analysis is failing

Tags: c#, sonarqube, code-analysis

My TFS 2013 integrated SonarQube build is failing for a couple of days.
I get the following error messages:

```
Run optional script before MSBuild

 Unhandled Exception: System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden.
 at System.Net.WebClient.DownloadFile(Uri address, String fileName)
 at System.Net.WebClient.DownloadFile(String address, String fileName)
 at SonarQube.Bootstrapper.BuildAgentUpdater.TryUpdate(String hostUrl, String targetDir, ILogger logger)
 at SonarQube.Bootstrapper.Program.PreProcess(IBuildAgentUpdater updater, IBootstrapperSettings settings, ILogger logger)
 at SonarQube.Bootstrapper.Program.Execute(String[] args, IBuildAgentUpdater updater, ILogger logger)
 at SonarQube.Bootstrapper.Program.Main(String[] args)
```

and later

```
Run optional script after Test Runner
 Execution failed. The specified executable does not exist: C:\Builds\39\{product name removed}\System_Main_Release_Code_Analysis\.sonarqube\bin\MSBuild.SonarQube.Internal.PostProcess.exe
 Post-processing failed. Exit code: 1
```

I do not have this MSBuild.SonarQube.Internal.PostProcess.exe anywhere.

And at the end I get:

```
 An error occurred while copying diagnostic activity logs to the drop location. Details: Forbidden
```

Since I don't have the diagnostics acitivity logs, I can only suspect what happens.
I suspect what happens is the following:

1. The begin phase of the SonarQube Analysis is triggered and the process tries to download SonarQube.MSBuild.Runner.Implementation.zip from the SonarQube website.
2. The internet access is blocked on the server and the download fails.
3. The SonarQube.MSBuild.Runner.Implentation.zip contains MSBuild.SonarQube.Internal.PostProcess.exe which would be extracted as part of the pre-Processing.
4. The post process fails because the PostProcess.exe was not downloaded.

I use the latest verisons of SonarQube and MSBuild.SonarQube.Runner.

What I need to know is this:
- Are my assumptions correct?
- Where does the pre process try to download a file from? (The server does have access to http://www.sonarsource.org)
- If my assumptions are wrong, what is keeping my build from analysing the source code?

Comment: The process attempts to download the zip from your SonarQube server i.e. the one specified in your SonaQube.Analysis.xml file (the default version of this file is in the same folder as the MSBuild.SonarQube.Runner.exe). Otherwise, your assumptions re correct: the XXX.Implementation.zip contains the pre- and post- processor exes.
Check: (1) your SonarQube.Analysis.xml file points to the correct URL and has the correct user credentials; (2) you have the latest version of the C# plugin installed on your SonarQube server.

Comment: The access was denied when the Sonar server was http:\\[servername]:9000. But it worked with http:\\localhost:9000.
The build is still failing but for another reason. It cannot write the  diagnostic activity logs to the drop locatio. (Details: Forbidden).

Comment: Does the build succeed if you take out the MSBuild.SonarQube.Runner steps?

Comment: @duncanpMS: The build is orange. It still has the `An error occurred while copying diagnostic activity logs to the drop location. Details: Forbidden` message at the end.

Comment: It doesn't look like a SonarQube issue then - more like a TFS build agent permissions problem. Have the permissions on the drop shares changed recently? Does the build work if you don't publish the drop?

Comment: The build is green now. The problem was the internet proxy settings.By checking **Bypass proxy server for local address** in the Local Area Network Settings of the build agent, the error about not being able to copy activity logs to the drop location disappeared.

Comment: Should SonarQube.MSBuild.Runner.Implementation.zip be placed somewhere on SonarQube server? I don't see any instructions for this file.

Comment: To answer my own question, Implementation.zip seems to be an embedded resource inside c# plugin which msbuild runner downloads from SQ server first thing.